# TcpClient listen for message

Tags: sockets, c++-cli, tcpclient

I'm writing a TCP/IP chat client, and I'm using `TcpClient` in `System::Net::Sockets` (in Visual C++ .NET) to send and receive data to/from the server. However I want the `TcpClient` reacts automatically when the server sends something to it, because the server only has the socket from `TcpClient` I don't want to add a `TcpListener` or any other thing to do this. So is there any way I can make the `TcpClient` listen to the connection, and has no influence on its sending and receiving data normally?

Comment: @ravenspoint But the client should be informed if there is a new message coming. The server simply needs a `send`, but how should client receive it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To check if a message has been received, you can check the Available property to get the number of bytes waiting to be read.

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcpclient.available(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcpclient.available%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)